# SQL Server Agent can't create excel file with SSMS Job task

Tags: sql-server, sql-job

i have a trouble with SQL Server Job, 
the job wont run properly to create or edit excel file when the owner user is logged out, in my case, we just moved to a new server, we already copy the server credential setting just like the old server but it still didnt work, in the old server, the job still work properly even if the owner user is logged out,
i hope someone here have the same issue just like me and want to share how to solve this,

Thankyou for your attention :D

Additional :

here's the error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5GMt.png)

and this is the job setting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHebI.png)

Comment: What do you mean "the owner user is logged out"? A login doesn't have to be connected for SQL Server to know who the owner of the job is (and the owner doesn't mean that's the credentials the agent job is run under). What is the *actual* error you are getting here and what are you actually  trying to do? All you've given us is a vague idea that you're creating an Excel file. How you're doing so, we have no idea about. Where it's begin created, again no idea. Explain the real problem here please.

Comment: Why doesn't your job work? Any errors or something?

Comment: Please post the full error text. This will contain the actual user that it is running under. Please explain if you are using the service account or a proxy account

Comment: hi guys, i already post the error and how i set the job

Comment: once i remote the user ba.admin to the server, the job will run properly with no fail, when i disconnect the remote server, the job will fail